# Trocar conteúdo de String por "$"

Tags: java, replace

Tenho uma String com um conteúdo e preciso fazer um replaceAll, porém o texto a ser substituído contém um cifrão "$" e isso causa o erro `Illegal group reference`.

Exemplo:

```
    String texto="teste {{texto}} teste";
    String trocar="_$_";
    texto=texto.replaceAll("\\{\\{texto\\}\\}", trocar);
```

Obs: Essa String "trocar" vem de um banco de dados, portanto não posso adicionar o \. O exemplo é apenas ilustrativo.

Comment: Tentou usar o scape? "\"?

Comment: Essa String "trocar" vem de um banco de dados. O exemplo é só ilustrativo. (editando a pargunta)

Comment: Voce pode forçar o escape do `$` por `\$`, editei minha resposta para exemplificar

Answer (score 2):

Faltou usar o escape `\`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String texto = "teste {{texto}} teste";
    String trocar = "_\\$_";
    texto = texto.replaceAll("\\{\\{texto\\}\\}", trocar);
    System.out.println(texto);
}
```

você ainda pode usar o `quote` para facilitar a busca:

```
String buscar = Pattern.quote("{{texto}}");
texto = texto.replaceAll(buscar, trocar);
```

agora o valor vindo de outra origem, você consegue resolver tentando fazer o escape do `$` por `\$` uma forma de fazer isto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String texto = "teste {{texto}} teste";
    String origem = "_$_";
    String trocar = origem.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("$"), "\\\\\\$");
    String buscar = Pattern.quote("{{texto}}");
    texto = texto.replaceAll(buscar, trocar);
    System.out.println(texto);
}
```

Comment: editei a pergunta... a String trocar vem de um banco de dados, portanto não posso adicionar o \\.

Comment: editei a resposta para exemplificar

Comment: Show! Funcionou, mas vc sabe me explicar o porque de tantas barras \ ?

Comment: sim, na verdade o simbolo `$` em expressão regular significa agrupamento geralmente você consegue utilizar `$1`. `$2` para grupo 1 grupo 2 ... dentro de uma expressao regular. ai no caso do \ o java utiliza como escape, desta forma você precisa escapar o `$` para ficar `\$` mais para escapar o \ vc precisa escapar o \ para \\ entao no final você tera um escape para cada caracter especial que será utilizado

Answer (score 2):

[String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) toma uma expressão regular correspondência padrão como seu primeiro parâmetro, e uma expressão regular de substituição padrão como seu segundo parâmetro - e $tem um significado específico em expressões regulares (em ambos os padrões de correspondência e padrões de substituição, embora em diferentes sentidos).

Basta usar [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) em vez disso, e eu suspeito que todos os seus problemas vão embora. Você só deve usar replaceAll quando você realmente deseja corresponder / substituir através de uma expressão regular - o que eu não acho que você faça neste caso.

Comment: Tem razão. Usando o replace funciona. Eu estava usando o replaceAll pois a String "texto" pode conter várias ocorrências de {{texto}} e achei que usando o replace apenas a primeira ocorrência seria substituída.

Answer (score 0):

Use o scape:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String texto="teste {{texto}} teste";
        String trocar="_\\$_";
        texto=texto.replaceAll("\\{\\{texto\\}\\}", trocar);
        System.out.println(texto);

    }
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta... a String trocar vem de um banco de dados, portanto não posso adicionar o \\.